# SQLite VACUUM command changes rowid values

Tags: c#, sqlite

When i run the command Vacuum in SQLite, the rowid values change. How do I prevent this?
for example:
If I use Vacuum to create an optimized backup, the row id values are different to the original.
VACUUM main INTO 'c:\sqlite\db\backup.db';

Answer (score 0):

It seems SQLite has a quirk:

If you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, the VACUUM does not change the values of that column.

good to know

Comment: That's documented behavior, yes. See  the last section of https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html